# How to use org.scalatest.Suite

Tags: scalatest

I'm trying to use scalatest suite using intellij idea like this :

```
class SampleTest extends org.scalatest.Suite {
    def myTest() {
       assert(true)
    }
}
(new SampleTest).execute()
```

I have added scalactic_2.11 and scalactic_2.11 to my pom file.The problem is that the SDK still cant resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems the problem is due to versioning. using the following version resolved the issue :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```